# What's the difference between @{} and [Hashtable]::Clear()?

Tags: .net, powershell

all!

I'm writing code that converts a standard INI file structure into one that is based on hashtables and arrays. For example, the INI snippet shown below:

```
[Book]
title="Moby Dick"
author="Herman Melville"
genre=fiction
genre=fantasy

[Book]
title="James and the Giant Peach"
author="Roald Dahl"
genre="fiction"
```

Would look like:

```
@{
    "Book" = [
        @{
            "title" = ["Moby Dick"];
            "author" = ["Herman Melville"];
            "genre" = ["fiction","fantasy"]
        },
        @{
            "title" = ["James and the Giant Peach"];
            "author" = ["Roald Dahl"];
            "genre" = ["fiction"]
        }
    ]

}
```

I wanted to account for INI files that have multiple identically-named sections and sections with multiple identically-named properties, hence this data structure. I know that I could use a tree to do the same thing, but I don't care much about its speed and this was easier to implement at the time I wrote it.

This is done by updating a hashtable that associates all properties within a section with their values (let's call it `$items`), then updating the main hashtable that associates each section with those aforementioned hashtables (let's call this one `$results`). The hashtables are global and the properties hashtable  is cleared upon iterating into new sections.

While I wrote code that does this and works well, I was stumped for a few minutes about the way in which Powershell clears hashtables. If I clear `$items` using `$items.Clear()`, **the hashtables associated with all elements in `$results` get cleared as well.** However, this does not happen if I "clear" it by stating `$items=@{}`.

I'm assuming that this happens because the hashtables in the former case are all references to the global hashtable and are independent objects in the latter. Is this what's happening?

Code is below; sorry if any of this is confusing (and that it's not in typical Powershell syntax). Replace `$items = @{}` with `$items = $items.Clear()` to replicate:

```
function parse ($file) {
    $result = @{}
    if (!(Test-Path $file)) {   
        write-host "File does not exist: $file"
    } elseif (!($data = cat $file)) {
        write-host "File has no data: $file"
    } else {
        $last_value = ""
        $last_data = ""
        $items = @{}
        foreach ($line_raw in $data | ?{$_.Trim().Length -gt 0}) {
            $line = $line_raw.TrimStart().TrimEnd()
            $first_char = $line[0]
            switch ($first_char) {
                ';' { 
                    continue 
                }
                '[' {
                    $key = $line -replace "\[|\]",""
                    if ($last_key) {
                        if (!($result.ContainsKey($last_key)))
                            { $result.Add($last_key,@($items)) }
                        else
                            { $result[$last_key] += $items }
                        if ($last_key -ne $key) 
                            { $items = @{} }                    
                    }
                    $last_key = $key
                }
                default {
                    $item , $data = $(
                        $sep = $line.indexOf('=')
                        $line.substring(0,$sep) , $line.substring($sep+1)
                    )
                    if (!$items.ContainsKey($item))
                        { $items.Add($item,@($data))    }
                    else 
                        { $items[$item] += $data }
                }
            }
        }
        $result
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate that behavior. Can you post the code as to how you're setting the different hashtables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable like `$items` refers to a storage location that in this case contains a hashtable.  When you assign the variable a value of `@{}` you are assigning to the variable a reference to a new, empty hashtable.  If nothing else references the original hashtable, the garbage collector will reclaim its memory.  Executing the `Clear()` method on a hashtable causes it to reset to an empty state.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was what was happening. Thanks again, Keith!

As a side question, is this the recommended way of parsing INI files with Powershell? While the example on The Scripting Guys uses simpler code, it doesn't seem to associate properties with their values, though it does associate sections with their properties. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, I think you mean: $items.Clear() and not $items = $items.Clear()

I'll have to take a closer look, because I don't see anything suspect yet, but I just wanted to let you know, to answer a more fundamental question, all the code above is pretty much doing what you can get for a few lines in Powershell by using the ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json cmdlets when applied to both your hashtables in memory and to the files you're storing. Give it a shot and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I meant `$items.Clear().` Does this work with the way this data is structured? And I thought this was included in Powershell v3+.

Comment: Yes it does. Take a look at how it converts hash tables to and from. I assumed you could use v3 because I didn't see anything to the contrary. If that's not the case you should really include that type of constraint in the question.